# OpenERP 6.0.4 - Stock Move Without picking_id

Tags: odoo

I'm having a weird problem in my Stock module.
once in a while when I check my stock move
I'll get a stock_move without picking_id in the database,
this is the example of the data:

```
id    |create_date         |write_date          |product_id |location_dest_id |location_id |picking_id  |State
------ -------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------------- ------------ ------------ ------
144661|2013-08-03 15:55:00 |2013-08-03 16:23:57 |88754      | 9               |341         |40194       |draft
144662|2013-08-03 16:20:41 |2013-08-03 16:21:43 |88749      | 9               |970         |            |draft
144663|2013-08-03 16:20:41 |2013-08-03 16:21:43 |76879      | 9               |970         |            |draft
144664|2013-08-03 16:29:08 |                    |88749      | 9               |970         |40194       |draft
144665|2013-08-03 16:29:08 |                    |76879      | 9               |970         |40194       |draft
```

Have any of you ever met this issue before?
can you tell me how can I trace the cause of this issue? 
thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

In OpenERP, the `stock.move` objects that have values for `picking_id` are *only* the `stock.move` objects that correspond directly to the `stock.picking` object. For example, each line on a delivery order is a `stock.move` object with the `picking_id` field referencing the delivery order (`stock.picking.out`).

However, there are often other `stock.moves` that are generated by an action. For instance, when using the `mrp` module to manufacture a product, a `stock.move` is generated from the manufacturing location to the default inventory location. This `stock.move` does not correspond to a picking, and will not have a `picking_id`, but it may be chained to a `stock.move` that *does* belong to a `stock.picking`.

It is possible to trace chained `stock.move` objects to their eventual `stock.picking` object by looking at the field `move_dest_id`. This field represents the `stock.move` object that is next in the chain. Looking at your data, I would expect the two moves that are missing `picking_ids` to correspond to the two moves below with the same `product_ids`.

Comment: thanks for your reply,
actually that data is from delivery order,
and the line without picking_id has the same data with the other line(example:the line with id 144662 and 144664)

there is no chained location in the location_id and location_dest_id,
and the move_dest_id is also null,